# how to use webview with fragment and maintain state in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fragments

I am new to the fragment can anybody tell how to use webview with fragment and maintain state  in android can anybody provide example

Thanks

Comment: this is a very broad question and you are not really explaining what your actual problem is. Try to invest more time into explaining what actual problem you have and what you want to achieve. In that way we may be better able to help you.